# File Socket Open and no Close Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, socketexception

I use Tomcat 5.5 Web Application.

This System is wav file or mp3 file download frequently.

Jenifer  Application Performance Management solution detected this problem.

Socket Open but no Close...

I check my program source.

But I don't use Socket Class or File Class..

How to resolve this problem.

> Thread Name
>
> http-8090-Processor12 / 0xd50 (isAlive: true, isDeamon: true,
>   isInterrupted: false, isSuspended: false)
>
> Application
>
> /REC_DATA/SO/2015/05/20/1234567.mp3
>
> HTTP Mothod : GET
>
> calltime : 2015-06-08/09:51:14
>
> rate time : 10,931.42 seconds
>
> status : APPRUN
>
> stacktrace
>
> java.net .SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  java.net
>   .SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)  java.net
>   .SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136) 
>   com.javaservice.lwst.SocketWrapper$OutputStreamWrap.write(Unknown
>   Source) 
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:747)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432) 
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347) 
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:770)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:118)  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:580)
>   org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560) 
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:361)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432) 
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347) 
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copyRange(DefaultServlet.java:2079)
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copy(DefaultServlet.java:1792)
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:874)
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:376)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   kr.co.cluecom.filters.tomcat5.ClueTC5RequestFilter.doFilter(ClueTC5RequestFilter.java:110)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:870)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net
>   .PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528) 
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net
>   .LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81) 
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
>
> active profile
>
> No
>
> Time
>
> Message
>
> 001
>
> 09:51:14.115
>
> http-8090-Processor12[native:d50]
>
> 002
>
> 09:51:14.115
>
> FILE-ROPEN E:\REC_DATA\SO\2015\05\20\1234567.mp3
>
> client IP
>
> 192.168.0.1

Comment: Where is the exception? What is a 'File Socket'? What's the question?

Comment: Sorry. I dont' know where exception happend.. I just use download  ex) http://192.168.0.1/REC_DATA\SO\2015\05\20\1234567.mp3 .. but it happend java.net .SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) Exception..